# Hardcode element position in CSS for non-JavaScript-users

Tags: javascript, css, position

I have a HTML-Document which is structured as shown in the following figure:

[image]

The red blocks which represent the text of the sidenotes are placed relatively to the footnote numbers in the text using CSS. If the text has many sidenotes and/or the texts of the sidenotes are long, the sidenotes overlap. To prevent such a behaviour I am using JavaScript to set the top margin of these elements in order to shift them downwards.

To prevent that the website is not usable without JavaScript enabled, I would like to hardcode the top margin value of the elements that need shifting down in the CSS-file. To take into account the different screen resolutions, I thought of using the CSS `@media`-query to set different top margins for other screen resolutions.

Example:

```
@media(min-width: 80em) {
    .container { width: 40em; }
    #sidenote-45 { margin-top: 15px; }
    [...]
}

@media(min-width: 60em) {
    .container { width: 30em; }
    #sidenote-56 { margin-top: 28px; }
    #sidenote-89 { margin-top: 12px; }
    [...]
}

[maybe more @media-queries for other screen sizes]
```

What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Please remember there are tons of screen sizes. gonna be too much.

Comment: For starters, use position:absolute or transforms instead.

Comment: @jkris Why? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute position relative to the container to place the notes at the left or right of the `div` and if you don't set `top` property the box maintains in its position aligned with the number. Something like this:

```css
.container {
  border: solid 2px black;
  background: white;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

sup {
  color: red;
}

.notes {
  position: absolute;
  left: -220px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  background: #8ac88a;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.right {
  left: auto;
  right: -220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In dolorum voluptate provident doloremque aperiam laboriosam ea, vel nihil illum, beatae nemo mollitia possimus, velit<sup>1<span class="notes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, et!</span></sup>  sapiente nobis! Expedita possimus incidunt nam laudantium corrupti eaque, eveniet fuga perferendis, enim praesentium vero voluptatibus adipisci, dicta blanditiis aliquid asperiores accusantium. Provident voluptate explicabo necessitatibus eos sequi
  modi non in nesciunt, debitis alias architecto doloremque sed<sup>2<span class="notes right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, et!</span></sup> quam voluptatem aut dolorem officia ipsa eum dicta optio delectus ullam
  aliquam! Dicta rerum praesentium, laudantium suscipit earum, voluptates placeat totam aperiam non atque consequatur cupiditate neque! Reiciendis consectetur quo, alias facilis officia totam illo minus? Vitae distinctio culpa nesciunt voluptate tempore!
  Error enim aperiam odio debitis culpa excepturi, minus molestias inventore amet recusandae<sup>3<span class="notes">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, et!</span></sup> fugit sit quasi qui ipsum. Aperiam quaerat tenetur,
  voluptatibus eaque. Voluptatum veniam, nihil accusamus nesciunt nobis dolore cumque amet asperiores qui, ducimus iusto voluptatibus.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I have to correct the positioning when the sidenotes overlap. I am calculating the new position using JavaScript. The question is if it is a good idea to hardcode the position in CSS so that users without JS enabled can see the sidenotes displayed correctly.

Comment: @Thorsten I try to find a pure CSS solution, maybe I misunderstood your question. Otherwise opinion based question are off-topic in SO. If your solution is good or not hasn't an objetive answer.